# When I exec a script with command "at", I get an infinite loop

Tags: bash, loops, at-job

I am learning bash shell and I'm a beginner.
Now, I have a script named for_test

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=3
until [ $var1 -eq 0 ]
do
    echo "Outer loop: $var1"
    var2=1
    while [ $var2 -lt 5 ]
    do
        var3=`echo "scale=4; $var1 / $var2" | bc`
    echo "    Inner loop:$var1 / $var2 = $var3"
    var2=$[ $var2 + 1 ]
    done
    var1=$[ $var1 - 1 ]
done >> temp.log.txt
```

When I exec it in the terminal, it works well.

```
Outer loop: 3
    Inner loop:3 / 1 = 3.0000
    Inner loop:3 / 2 = 1.5000
    Inner loop:3 / 3 = 1.0000
    Inner loop:3 / 4 = .7500
Outer loop: 2
    Inner loop:2 / 1 = 2.0000
    Inner loop:2 / 2 = 1.0000
    Inner loop:2 / 3 = .6666
    Inner loop:2 / 4 = .5000
Outer loop: 1
    Inner loop:1 / 1 = 1.0000
    Inner loop:1 / 2 = .5000
    Inner loop:1 / 3 = .3333
    Inner loop:1 / 4 = .2500
```

But when I exec like this:

```
at -f for_test 11:10
```

When the time has come, the script is executed, but I get an infinite loop.
Here's the log.

```
Outer loop: 3
    Inner loop:3 / 1 = 3.0000
    Inner loop:3 / 1 = 3.0000
    Inner loop:3 / 1 = 3.0000
    ……
```

And I found $var2 always equals 1.

What do I do wrong?

---

My ubuntu version and bash version.

```
$ uname -a
Linux android_su 2.6.35-32-generic #67-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 5 19:39:49 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

---

@konsolebox
The second command works fine. Thanks.
But why does the first command not work? I'm still confuesd.
First and second commands are all executed with /bin/sh.

```
$ at -f for_test 14:16
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 22 at Thu Aug 29 14:16:00 2013

$ echo "/bin/bash /home/android_su/android/source/linux_learned/for_test" | at 14:19
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 23 at Thu Aug 29 14:19:00 2013
```

Comment: This code is working for me with `at`. **Fedora 16**

Comment: As for the second command there's still a warning. It just shows that commands are interpreted through /bin/sh. But you passed a command that would call `/bin/bash `/path/to/sh` so `at` calls `sh` to read the command `/bin/bash ...` then `/bin/bash` is called with an argument of `/path/to/sh` and bash reads the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use internal functions instead as PATH is not always defined in crontabs and likes:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=3
until (( var1 == 0 ))
do
    echo "Outer loop: $var1"
    var2=1
    while (( var2 < 5 ))
    do
        var3=$(echo "scale=4; $var1 / $var2" | bc)
        echo "    Inner loop:$var1 / $var2 = $var3"
        (( ++var2 ))
    done
    (( --var1 ))
done >> temp.log.txt
```

Make sure you run your script as bash as well like this:

```
echo "/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh" | at 11:10
```

Or

```
at 11:10 <<EOF
/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh
EOF
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I get an infinite output "Outer loop: 3"

Comment: @android_su Make sure you're running it with bash (/bin/bash) and not with other shells.

Comment: @android_su I made an update showing some examples to run it explicitly with bash.

Comment: I think the first line "#!/bin/bash" decide which shell I use, am I right?

Comment: @android_su Sometimes you can't rely on it much if you're calling the file through another scheduler.

Comment: @android_su I saw your update. /bin/sh could be a different shell or is more POSIX-compatible than the true bash (/bin/bash) in which some features doesn't work.. Probably the reason as well why your variables don't change. `at` only calls /bin/sh for its -f option.

Comment: @android_su With the first command the execution is like `at->sh->script`, while on the second command it's `at->sh->bash->script`.

Comment: How can I specify the bash to execute my script?

Comment: @android_su You already did with the second command but you can't prevent `at` to use /bin/sh as its default shell interpreter for anything that gets into its input.

Comment: @android_su commands like `bash /something something` is not really interpreted by `at` itself. It requires another shell to do it, and it is programmed to only use `/bin/sh`, that is why you have to wrap the script with another shell like /bin/bash.

Answer (score 2):

When using `at -f` the commands in the script are parsed *as if you typed them in*.  That means that `#!/bin/bash` is just a comment and does not cause your script to execute under `bash`.  As `at` would have told you if you had not used `-f`:

```
$ at 0900
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
```

The problem with using `/bin/sh` is that true Bourne shell does not support the math extensions you are using like `$[ 1 + 2 ]`.  Those were introduced by `ksh` (afaik) and are now available in `bash`.  Some people may se different results with their system `/bin/sh` because not all systems use the same `sh`.  Some just use `bash` but there are more Bourne-like variants such as `ash` and probably whatever shell is in `busybox`.

You just need to make a wrapper that calls your script (just a file with `/path/to/script` in it) and use *that file* as the input to `at -f`

Comment: @ruakh: The `$[ 1 + 2 ]` math is supported by `ksh` (original source, afaik) and `bash` but not classic `sh`.  However different systems use different shells for `sh` and some are more primitive than others (e.g. `ash`)